# Printeradress independent from Serial number

Tags: 14.04, printing

I have a setup with Ubuntu 14.04 where a printer is operated by a small c programm. Because I have multiple identical systems, I own multiple printers of the same type (Dymo LabelWriter 450). My problem is that the printer is recognized by its serial number (usb://Unknown/Printer?serial=XXXXXXX). How can I manage to get a recognition by its type and not serial?

Comment: Could you please explain how *exactly* you configure and use *which* program to *what end*?

Comment: I added the printer using Ubuntu's built in system-config-printer (v 1.5.7, I upgraded to 16.04 in the mean time). There I just followed the steps Add printer --> it was plugged in via USB --> selected --> installed a manual ppd. In my opinion my program doesnt influences it since I adress the printer with a system call  to `lpr`.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question if you want to clarify something or add information? It's much better to have everything in one place instead of scattered throughout the comment section. Additionally, comments may be removed for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Which program do you use to print? Maybe it possesses a mean to specify a particular printer device in some other way.